# send https post request with authentication in ruby

Tags: ruby, curl

I got a curl here:

```
curl https://test-api.pin.net.au/1/charges -u your-secret-api-key: \ 
 -d "amount=400" \ -d "currency=USD" \
```

how can I use `net/http` to post this request? It include the ssl and authentication.

Comment: Did you read the documentation for [POST](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.1/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html#class-Net::HTTP-label-POST) and [Basic Authentication](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.1/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html#class-Net::HTTP-label-Basic+Authentication)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTTP#post_form will execute directly

```
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'

url = URI.parse('https://test-api.pin.net.au/1/charges')
req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(url.path)
req.basic_auth 'user', 'pass'
req.use_ssl = true
req.form_data({'your-secret-api-key' => 'val1', 'amount' => 'val2', 'currency' => "USD"})

resp = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port).start {|http| http.request(req) }
puts resp
```

Comment: It is very helpful ,thanks mate. but i make a little change. I already post my answer under the question. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I solved this question now. here is the answer

```
uri = URI.parse('https://test-api.pin.net.au/1/charges')  
Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port, :use_ssl => uri.scheme == 'https') do |http  
req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.path)  
req.basic_auth 'user', 'pass'  
req.set_form_data({ 'amount' => 'val2', 'currency' => "USD"}  
http.request(req))  
end
```